# how to modify tomcat8 acceptCount in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

how to modify the tomcat default thread count using spring boot?
when i use spring mvc,i can find the tomcat,and modify the  in conf/server.xml,then i modify the maxProcessors and acceptCount,but in spring boot i can't do that.

```
in org.apache.catalina.connector, i can't find the properties.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to check what everything you can modify via properties: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

```
server.tomcat.max-threads = 0 # number of threads in protocol handler
```

otherwise you will have to get your hands dirty with programmatic configuration - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-tomcat by providing your own `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`

Comment: Http11NioProtocol can do that , extends org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol

Answer (score 3):

acceptCount not support to modify in properties files, you can you following code to modify:

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

    tomcatFactory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
            //tomcat default nio connector
            Http11NioProtocol handler = (Http11NioProtocol)connector.getProtocolHandler();
            //acceptCount is backlog, default value is 100, you can change which you want value in here
            handler.setBacklog(100);
        }
    });

    return tomcatFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In current spring boot it should be possible through **server.tomcat.accept-count** application property, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#server-properties